# ¿Que librería puedo usar en c++ para agilizar una búsqueda?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, librería, busqueda

Quiero hacer un buscador en c++ pero cargo una gran cantidad de datos, primero utilice una búsqueda secuencial y demora mucho, luego ordene los datos y aplique búsqueda binaria, mejoro pero no lo suficiente. He estado revisando y veo que hay estructuras que hacen esto pero no se cual usar, y si me pudieran dar un ejemplo de cómo usarlas estaría agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

En lo personal me gusta utilizar el stdlib.h para los ordenamientos, búsquedas, mejoran las conversiones, memoria, tienen control de procesos.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
```

Comment: Por favor evitemos responder a preguntas basadas en opiniones pues estas terminan cerradas